# How do I animate an object along a custom path in canvas?

Tags: html, canvas

I have a series of paths (with curve points) created in Illustrator. How do I send my circle to follow along these paths in Canvas?

I can set the paths to a line through a svg -> canvas converter, but that doesn't help me animate anything along that line.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest checking out something like [CAAT.js](http://labs.hyperandroid.com/static/caat/). The first demo does pretty much exactly what you are looking for.

[CAAT.js follow path demo](http://labs.hyperandroid.com/static/CAAT-Samples/demos/demo1/path.html)