# Jquery Race Circuit

Tags: jquery, canvas

I am creating a web application that supports both in desktop and mobile. I have a banner that contains a race circuit and a pointer. My question is how to make travel the pointer over the circuit path in Jquery. I know it will be doable in Flash. But I want to know if it is doable in Jquery. Please help me to achieve this. Thanks.[image]

Comment: you might be interested in that old fiddle of mine : http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/XDxcc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with an SVG animation:

[example](http://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/)

or else with a canvas animation:

[SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164433/how-do-i-animate-an-object-along-a-custom-path-in-canvas)